# cursor.skip() is expensive, is there alternate approach

Tags: mongodb

While going through
[cursor.skip() MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.skip/) I read that this is expensive approach and I totally understand it why it is expensive as cursor has to go through from start to execute this skip. And in the below paragraph they wrote

> Consider using range-based pagination for these kinds of tasks. That is, query for a range of objects, using logic within the application to determine the pagination rather than the database itself. This approach features better index utilization, if you do not need to easily jump to a specific page.

I don't understand this part, how this overcome the "expensive(ness)" of skip() operation.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using cursor.skip(N) the server finds all the matching data and then skips over the first N matching documents.

When using range based pagination (ie. with a date range) the server will only find and return the matching documents. If the property you base your pagination on is indexed the index will also be used.

The difference is the amount of data the server has to read in the two situations.

Comment: i totally understand you now, thanks Martin i was stuck in range-based pagination thing.. thanks a lot